# How to fix text on the container

Tags: html, css

### here is the Jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/dpR4D in CSS First is the bootstrap in the end is my style

My goal is to make something like this http://www.degordian.com/. You see the text 'Makes You curious' is fixed on that container and the background is fixed too. I'm trying to do this on my website, for the background I've succeeded by changing the `background-attachment:fixed;` but for the text when i do this

```
.jumbotron . container { position : fixed }
```

look what happens:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4EFR.png]

1. all the text goes to the left
2. when scrolling the container stays allways on the page but i want it to disapear after the white div (graphic design - web design - development)

Comment: Don't use `position: fixed` alone. It should always be used with some coordinates. Alone it is same as using `position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px` which will be top left corner of screen. Try providing some coordinates (left and top values). That will solve your issue. As for the issue of it disappearing after white div, keep the z-index of the text lower than the div container.

Comment: This isn't a good SO question. I can't follow your links because I'm in work and therefore I've no idea what you're trying to achieve, and I've no idea what your results are.

Comment: We really need to see your HTML and your CSS for the relevant issue.

Comment: Can you Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and paste the link here?

Comment: here is the Jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/dpR4D in CSS First is the bootstrap in the end is my style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a z-index problem.

Try this:

```
.jumbotron .container { position : fixed; z-index: 1; }
```

For the next element (the white one with Graphic Design | Web Design | Development), try this:

```
<your element> { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
```

Comment: Please provide a link or a JSfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you can try forcing a position: relative; z-index: 1 on the .jumbotron, and then a position: relative; z-index: 2; on the second element (the white one with Graphic Design | Web Design | Development)

Comment: here is the Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dpR4D/

in CSS First is the bootstrap in the end is my style

Comment: Add this to your CSS: #section-1.jumbotron { position: relative; z-index: 1; } #services.services { background: #fff; }

Comment: Hi RazvanDH this worked! but :
1.the text + my logo all goes to the left
2.i want the text to not be showed on all the page after that services section , because after that it shows again

the fault i've made before is that i didnt put the background-color to that services part ! please were almost getting this to be fixed , thanks you

Comment: Hi again i've added a div before the services and after footer .all
and i gived it z-index:2; worked fine
but still the text of the jumbotron in the left side ..

Comment: waiting your answer RazvanDH ! :(

Comment: That is another problem, and not related to the current thread. But your solution is adding this in your CSS: #section-1.jumbotron .container { width: 100%; }

Comment: Yes i'vge fugure it out yesterday,
But thanks you ! :)

Comment: if my solution helped you, select this as best answer please. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change the z-index of the white box you have there to 1 put it on the front. The z index property is for layering and the smaller the number is the closer to the front.

Comment: user3604578 can you include a jsfiddle please

Comment: here is the Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dpR4D/

in CSS First is the bootstrap in the end is my style

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index:0;` to `.jumbotron . container`

and `z-index:5; /* Any value > 0*/` to others.

Also

`position:absolute;` instead of `fixed` may help.

Comment: Tryed it like this :
.jumbotron .container{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:0;
}

.services{
    z-index:5;
}

Nathing happens,
Position absolute the text is not fixed ..